# Windows7 ignores part of the path (powershell in my case)

Tags: windows-7, path

windows 7 does not activate the path for powershell.

1) C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 exsists in my path

```
    C:\GitRepository>path
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
```

2) can't run powershell from cmd implicitly

```
    C:\GitRepository>powershell 
'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

3) but it runs explicitly

```
   C:\GitRepository>c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\user\Androidwork\WebDevelopment\GitRepository> exit

C:\Users\user\Androidwork\WebDevelopment\GitRepository>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Filburt: This is a path issue, and not specific to PowerShell.

Comment: Joey, 
1) you are correct.
2) changed the title per your answer.
3) Many thanks for your help

Comment: Well, it was mainly aimed at the editor who added the [tag:powershell] tag ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem are the spaces in front of the path to PowerShell. Just remove them, i.e.:

```
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
```

Comment: Joey,
Small note. 
As far as I checked leading spaces cause windows to ignore only the specific path item but windows still treats the rest of the path correctly.

Comment: Well, yes, it doesn't break everything, but you still should not do it ;)

Comment: Didn't solve my problem exactly, but led me to recognise that I needed the full path to the Powershell.exe (c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe) in my .cmd file as it was not on the Path.

Answer (score 0):

I found that one of the programs I installed removed the ; in the path separating the Powershell path from the next path.  ;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell**v1.0\c:**\program files\other program.  Once the semi-colon was put into place, powershell.exe launched successfully.